# How do I store my count value in locally in the ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework

Hi guys I am working on this live project where I want to store the quantity/count values (1,2,3....) locally. I just need a little guidance with the code. I am learning ionic. This is my ts files code snippet.

```
this.cartArr.push(items);
this.dataPrint = this.cartArr;
let item =this.dataPrint;
let selected = {};

for(let obj of item){
    if(selected[obj.ITEMID]){
        selected[obj.ITEMID].count++;
    }else{
        selected[obj.ITEMID] = {...obj,count: 1};
    }
}

this.selectedItems = Object.keys(selected).map(key => selected[key])
console.log('items: ',this.selectedItems);
this.total = this.selectedItems.reduce((a, b) => a + (b.count * b.RATE), 0);
this.storage.set('cartItems',this.selectedItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

To store data locally we generally prefer Local DB and for that Ionic have also good and easy plugin to store data locally in sqlite.

**Plugin to store data locally in Sqlite:**

[Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)

**How to use?**

1. Follow the instruction  from above link to add plugin into ur app.

> $ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
>
> $npm install --save @ionic/storage

2. Set Data:

   //set a key/value

   ```
   this.storage.set('key', 'Value');
   ```
3. Get Data:

   ```
     //get a key/value pair
     this.storage.get('age').then((val) => {
       console.log('Your age is', val);
     });
   ```

Hope this will help you to store your data in local DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use Local storage it works without internet. Storage is working online it needs internet to retrieve data. You have set data you can get data from storage by using the 'cartItems' key.

Comment: I just want to store the count value. How to do that